# Can't create a folder on my newly created partition

Tags: permissions

If I have a partition: /dev/sda3 how do I take ownership so that I can create folders?

I tried:

sudo chown -R chris:chris /dev/sda3
sudo chmod -R 755 /dev/sda3

but when I right click within the folder 'Create new folder' is still greyed out?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

First mount your partition. Then as root, or using sudo, change ownership of the mount point to your user account with this:

```bsh
chown -R you:you /mount/point/
```

Or, you can go to file manager and enter the mount point. Then right click and select "Open in terminal". Now execute this:

```bsh
chown -R you:you /mount/point/
```

You should now be able create files and directories with your user account from anywhere including file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read/write directly to block devices--/dev/sd? devices.

You need to format and mount partitions.

Ubuntu automounts most partions under the /media folder with a GUID mount point.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Comment: I have mounted the partition already. I want to copy data into the partition.

Comment: What is the mount point?  Type mount from your command prompt, and if you have mounted the partition, it will say something like
/dev/sda5 on /some/other/folder type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
   The /some/other/folder is where you need to change the permissions.

Comment: /dev/sda3 on /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9 type ext2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)

Comment: So i should try: Sudo chown -R chris:chris /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9 sudo chmod -R 755 /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9?

Comment: You need to access the partition from /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9  It might appear as something nicer on your desktop.

Comment: What does ls -lR /media say for the permissions?

Comment: sorry I don't follow. I am wholly new from today in Ubuntu.

Comment: A lot :-) too fast for me. I typed in the command and a flood of text streamed past.

Comment: Welcome to Linux.  What I am getting at with the ls command is to find out first what the permissions are on the /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9 folder.  You may not need to change anything.

Comment: type this  >cd /media  then >ls -l   (but don't type the > symbol)

Comment: So we're trying to find out what the permissions are on this folder. Is that what /media/.... is? Is that a folder? How do I find out what the permissions are?

Comment: ls -l will tell you something like:
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 Sep 24 14:35 0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea not to put my 50 odd gb of data (photos, music etc...) all in my home folder. I thought that from a structure / backup perspective it would be a good idea to distinguish all my archive files from current files and create a partition that would gain me security if, say, I chose to reiinstall Ubuntu. But after creating the partition it seems quite tricky just to get in a position to copy my files over...

Comment: Your plan is sensible.  Once you sort out the access aspects, you just need to create a symbolic link (symlink) from your home directory to your archive.

Comment: ls -l delivered:drwxr-xr-x 2 chris chris 16384 Dec  8 16:31 lost+found

Comment: so we need to find out what the permissions are on subfolder(s) in the /media folder.  So cd in to the /media folder, just type in ls -l.  Are you using ubuntu?  I'm not such a fan of standard Ubuntu desktop anymore, I prefer Linux Mint or Xubuntu.  I have found that new users have a hard with the new Unity system.

Comment: total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 chris chris 4096 Dec  8 16:31 0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9

Comment: yes I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, it looks like /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9 is ready to for you copy your files to.

Comment: You might find this page helpful:   https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/files.html

Comment: I am sorry to interrupt :). This is a QA site, not forum; read [about](http://askubuntu.com/about). Please @David update your answer with the summary of your comments, so someone else can catch the steps to solve the same problem wihout reading the discussion in the comments. And keep update it until the problem solved (or not solved) :)

Comment: @BornToCode, I understand what you are saying.  I would have gone to chat, but Chris does not have enough user points.  The solution was that Chris needed to access his files through the a subfolder of the /media folder.